# Chai assertion 'expect' to check all item of array to have a property

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

I need to check the existence and validate a property in all json objects in an array.

I would like something like that:

```
except([{id:1, data:10},{id:2, data:20},{id:3, data:30}]).to.have.all.property('data').that.is.a('number')
```

result: **test succeed**

```
except([{id:1, data:10},{id:2, value:20},{id:3, data:30}]).to.have.all.property('data').that.is.a('number')
```

result: **test failed**

```
except([{id:1, data:'red'},{id:2, data:20},{id:3, data:30}]).to.have.all.property('data').that.is.a('number')
```

result: **test failed**

Comment: it doesn't appear to be anything different about it? Could you clarify the unit tests? They look pretty much the same.

Comment: Are you using 'expect'? You have 'except' in your code samples here